# What does "he wasn’t very subtle about" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

I am wondering what "he wasn’t very subtle about" means in the following sentences:

> Hannah speaks first. ‘Olivia.’
>
> The cave replies in a whisper: *Olivia, Olivia, Olivia*.
>
> ‘God,’ Hannah says, ‘that echo. Did your ex . . . did he do anything
> to you? Someone I know—’ She stops, starts again, ‘my sister, Alice.
> She had this boyfriend when she was at university. And he reacted
> really badly to the break-up. I mean, really *really* badly—’
>
> I wait for Hannah to say more, but she doesn’t. Instead she takes the
> bottle from me and has a very long drink, about four shots’ worth.
>
> ‘No, it wasn’t anything like that,’ I say. ‘Yeah, Callum was a bit of
> a shit. I mean, **he wasn’t very subtle about** hooking up with Ellie
> straight after. But he was the one who broke it off, so it wasn’t
> that.’ I grab the bottle from her, take a big gulp. I can taste her
> lipstick on the rim. ‘It was in the summer holidays after term had
> ended. I was staying at Jules’s place in Islington, while she was away
> for work for a few days.’

- Lucy Foley, *The Guest List*, Chapter 17

The day before the wedding, after the rehearsal dinner, Hannah and Olivia went out to a cave to talk about Olivia's breakup.

In this part, I am wondering what "he wasn’t very subtle about" means.

Comment: He immediately took up with another woman without making any pretence of needing time to get over the break-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word subtle can have various meanings depending on context. In this case I would say the intent is that of “not ostentatious”, or “inconspicuous”. There is at times an expectation that a former partner (particularly when the breakup is recent) who gets together with someone else would not publicly advertise it, out of respect for the former partner. Instead it would be done in a subtle manner, such that the former partner would either not find out about it at all, or be able to ignore it. In this excerpt the narrator is saying that Callum did not do it in a subtle manner.